# Computed property don't update after save operation

Tags: ember.js, controller, ember-data, handlebars.js

I'm really stuck in the problem.

I got a simple object controller:

```
ContractorApp.ContractController = Em.ObjectController.extend
  needs: ['application']

  bidSize: ( ->
    @get( 'model.budget' )
    ).property 'model', 'model.budget'

  bidden: ( ->
    @get('controllers.application.model.bids').findBy( 'contract', @get('model') )
    ).property 'model', 'controllers.application.model.bids.@each'

  actions:
    make_bid: ()->
        bid = @store.createRecord 'bid',
            contract: @get( 'model' )
            proposal: @get( 'bidSize' )
        bid.save().then ->
            alert 'cool!'
```

Contractors can bid on contracts. Their bid by default in my system is equal to contract's budget. So when contractor opens a contract (I suppose property 'model' changes) I want bid size in bidding input changes to default:

```
<h3>{{title}}</h3>
<p>{{ description }}</p>
<p class="em-success">{{ budget }} руб</p>

{{#if bidden}}
<p>You have already proposed <strong>{{bidden.proposal}}</strong></p>
{{else}}
{{ input value=bidSize class="form-control" }}
<button {{action "make_bid"}} class="btn btn-ar btn-primary">Propose it!</button>
{{/if}}
```

So it work perfectly before the user make a bid (make_bid action). after that 'bidden' property calculates as supposed, but bidSize don't called ever.
I use EmberData. Application controller got a user account as a model. It has all bidden bids in his 'bids' property.
What am I doing wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: The only obvious flaw I can see in your code is that you're using `bids.@each` instead of `bids.[]` (which the [Ember documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#property__each) says is incorrect). But I don't see why that would affect `bidSize` not being calculated. Are you sure it's not being called when you click the button?

Comment: @GJK yeah, I placed debugger there: nor the code stopped there neither the value changed ;(

Answer (score 0):

What is `budget` here? Does its value change on `make_bid` execution? Looks like the reason is in this property.